# Unable to install WebdriverAgent on iOS simulator, getting error on Appium Desktop

Tags: ios-simulator, appium-ios, appium-desktop

**Error Received:**
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100

{
"platformName": "iOS",
"platformVersion": "15.4",
"deviceName": "iPhone 12",
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"UDID": "DEDB43E2-717B-44C6-963E-34847B5E8D90",
"app": "/Users/Tester/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/capital-behvzukvlynvsydkreldaexdsiot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CapitalAM.app"

I am using Appium Desktop.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed when I updated the Appium GUI to the latest version 1.22.2.